# How to use localStorage with jest nextjs

Tags: unit-testing, next.js, jestjs, local-storage, react-testing-library

I am testing my nextjs web app with react testing library jest.
I am using localstorage to store the jwt for logged in users.
And in my app i am using useEffect to fetch the content from the server on every page

```
let token = localStorage.getItem("token");

useEffect(() => {
    if(!token) return;
    // Fetch from sever and set
    let res = axios.get(.....);
    setData(res.data);
}, [token]);
```

But the problem is i am not able to set the localStorage so that the app can get the token from there.

I've tried jest-localstorage-mock package but didn't fullfill my requirement. I just need a way to provide my app with the token from localstorage. Does anyone know how can this be solved. Any possible way to set the localstorage?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.